# Node API function returning array of strings instead of objects

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'd like to return an array of JSON objects from this function but I'm having issues with the formatting. I'm new to Node.js and hoping to understand it better.

```
function getItems (callback) {
  connection.query(SQL_getItems, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    callback(null, results.map((item) => `{'name': '${item.name}', 'value': '${item.value}'}`));
  });
}
```

The current JSON looks like this:

```
["name: test, value: 1","name: test2, value: 0"]
```

What I want is an array of JSON objects

```
[{"name": "test","value": "1"},{"name": "test2","value": "0"}]
```

I've tried tweaking the formatting, but can't get it quite right. I tried JSON.parse but it's already valid (but not ideal) JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with using  template string like this:

```
`{'name': '${item.name}', 'count': '${item.value}'}`
```

the `map` function will return an array of string, that is what you've got. To return an JSON object as expected, I think your code should be:

`results.map(item => JSON.stringify({name: item.name, count: item.value}))`

p/s: If I remember exactly, you can pass the accept header as `application/json` to get your work done automatically with `res.send({<JS object>})`.

**UPDATED**:
Does your result looks like this, I tried but get diffrent result from yours:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. that's helpful. One issue though, the quotes are escaped with slashes. I should have mentioned, that's one of the things I've been running into as I try to figure this out: `["{\"name\":\"test\",\"value\":1}","{\"name\":\"test2\",\"value\":0}"]`

Comment: Thank. I think,  adding more info like `console.log(results); console.log(typeof results)` on your code will be useful for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thelonglqd for pointing me in the right direction. The issue was that the results were already in the format I needed, so I was double encoding them.

```
function getItems (callback) {
  connection.query(SQL_getItems, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    callback(null, JSON.stringify(results));
  });
}
```